# How much math background do you need to understand how category theory is applied to Haskell?

Tags: category-theory

Basically, how much math background do you need to understand how category theory is applied to Haskell? If you already have mathematical maturity, can you jump right into it, or should you be familiar with certain subjects in algebra?

Comment: *understand* is a vague word. What is your context? Do you know some Haskell and want to know it better, or are you asking this before you started learning? Does the subject of category theory itself interests you, or are you mostly interested in its application?

Comment: I want to learn about Haskell and category theory but I have just heard about them, and I'm also interested in how category theory was used to develop concepts in Haskell such as monads, and why it's needed. I have a couple of resources about this that I'm about to open up, so I'm wondering if I need an advanced mathematical background to get how category theory is applied.

Comment: I would strongly suggest learning Haskell before trying to get into category theory.

Comment: I think this question has already been answered in http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3028/is-category-theory-useful-for-learning-functional-programming.  Please see the answers there.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to learn category theory without regards to Haskell (and if you don't have it, Haskell without regards to category theory). A book such as Lawvere's *Conceptual Mathematics* is a good start. Awodey is also recommended, and Leinster's recent *Basic Category Theory*.